# jQuery Google Maps - open infowindow on click

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am running a google map from HTML data and I really need to be able to click on rows (divs) to open the relevant marker. I was hoping to add an onclick within an `.each()` function but I cant get anything I have tried to work.

Basically if clicking on each row could open the relevant infowindow it would solve all my problems :)

Help would be much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var myOptions = {
           zoom: 4,
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.900557, 174.885971),
           mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
           disableDefaultUI: true
        };
        var icon = "img/marker.png";
        $(function() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
            // grab data attributes from html
            $('.row').each(function( index ){
                var rLat = $(this).data("coordinates").lat;
                var rLong = $(this).data("coordinates").long;
                var rTitle = $(this).find('.itemtitle a').html();
                var rTel = $(this).find('.tel').html();
                var rAdd = $(this).find('.add').html();
                var contentString = '<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">' + rTitle + '</h4><strong>' + rTel + '</strong><br /><br />' + rAdd + '</div>';
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng( rLat, rLong );
                var otherMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: icon
                });
                // click actions
                google.maps.event.addListener(otherMarkers, 'click', (function(otherMarkers, index) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent( contentString );
                        infowindow.open( map, otherMarkers );
                    }
                })(otherMarkers, index));               
            });
        });

        $(function() {
            $(".leftblock .ctrlholder:nth-child(2)").addClass("last");
            $(".leftblock .ctrlholder:nth-child(3)").addClass("last");
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" data-coordinates='{"lat" : -41.407493, "long" : 174.584122}'>
    <h4 class="itemtitle"><a href="">Title</a></h4>
    <p class="centralregion">Address</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="add">Post Address</li>
        <li class="tel">tel</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="filter3"></span>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already loop over all the rows to create markers you can add a click handler to each row that will click on the marker

after adding marker event listener:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(otherMarkers......);
```

Add a row click handler that triggers a marker click:

```
/* "this" is the row instance*/
$(this).click(function(){
 google.maps.trigger( otherMarkers ,'click')
})
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply, for some reason best known to itself this click function is totally ignored, I tried something simular to this with no joy, even doing a console log on the click shows nothing :(

Comment: it seems if the click function is inside that loop it doesnt work

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net, just need a couple or three rows to test it with

Comment: you placed the click handler inside the map listener not after it.... demo not working due to missing google file. Put row handler after `})(otherMarkers, index)); `

Comment: I did try it after the map listener too. I have included everything in the external resources, but the map doesnt work on fiddle. Any idea what you think is missing for this to work?

Comment: i had a js conflict by the looks of it, and now get an error, TypeError: google.maps.trigger is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

google.maps.trigger( otherMarkers ,'click')

Comment: haven't played with Google maps in long time...try `google.maps.event.trigger`

Comment: thanks very much, it turns out I have a really annoying js conflict, thanks so much for your help very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is slightly convoluted but has the advantage of being economical of memory.

```
$(function() {
    var myOptions = {
       zoom: 4,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-40.900557, 174.885971),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       disableDefaultUI: true
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var icons = {
        'dflt': "../images/map_icons/beach-certified.png",
        'selected': "../images/map_icons/harbour-guest.png"
    };
    var infoTemplate = '<div style="text-align:left"><h4 style="color:#0068a6;font-size:16px;margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;">%Title</h4><strong>%Tel</strong><br /><br />%Add</div>';
    var seletedMarker = null;

    //Function for composing the info string on the fly.
    //This avoids needing to store fully composed info strings in a closure,
    //on the offchance that they will be viewed.
    function composeInfoString(row) {
        var $row = $(row);
        return infoTemplate
            .replace('%Title', $row.find('.itemtitle a').html())
            .replace('%Tel', $row.find('.tel').html())
            .replace('%Add', $row.find('.add').html());
    }

    //closure-forming function to trap row and marker
    function clickHandler(row, marker) {
        return function() {
            if(seletedMarker) {
                seletedMarker.setIcon(icons.dflt);//revert seletedMarker's icon to .dflt
            }
            infowindow.setContent( composeInfoString(row) );
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
            marker.setIcon(icons.selected);//Set marker's icon to .seleted
            seletedMarker = marker;//Remember the currently selected marker so it can be reverted to default next time round.
        };
    }

    $('.row').each(function( index, row ) {
        var $row = $(row);
        var coords = $row.data("coordinates");
        //console.log([coords.lat, coords.lng].join());
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( Number(coords.lat), Number(coords.lng) ),
            icon: icons.dflt,
            map: map
        });
        var fn = clickHandler(row, marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', fn);
        $row.data('clickFn', fn);//associate fn with row.
    });

    //Delegate handling of row clicks upward (to closest common row container).
    $(document).on('click', '.row', function() {
        var fn = $(this).data('clickFn');
        if(fn) fn();//this is the functionality you seek
    });
});
```

The economies are twofold :

- By composing the info-string on the fly, you avoid the need to store fully composed info strings in closures (one per marker/row), on the off-chance that they will be viewed.
- By attaching `fn` (pragmatically speaking, a "closure") to each row as a `.data()` item, and delegating click handling upwards, you can exploit the same closure used when clicking the marker directly without the need for an additional function wrapper per marker/row.

These kinds of economies can be significant when working with many markers, and otherwise do no harm.

Also, you might like to consider changing your coordinate longitude property from `long` to `lng`. In the code, this will avoid `.long`, which can give problems in some browsers. `long` is one of many underlying language keywords that should be avoided as js object property identifiers.

### Edit

Now tested - See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acMS8/5/).
Various fixes are reflected above.

### Edit 2

Code modified to swap-out selected marker icon- See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acMS8/6/).

Comment: really great response, and some great points, I will take all this onboard to make it more efficent. thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: See edit above. Note: In jsfiddle there's a knack to adding resources that don't naturally end in a file extension. You have to dupe the parser with a faux `.js` at the end.

Comment: thanks again, that is really helpful. How easy would it be to change the map icon used at the same time, so its like a selected icon? thank you very much for all your help

Comment: I think your code for changing the marker graphic is correct - ie an `icon:...` option in `new google.maps.Marker({...})`. As you will see, I commented out that option to show Google's default markers. Otherwise your `img/marker.png` doesn't point to anything when served from jsfiddle and no markers show. Should by OK when served from your own server, providing the image is in place in the right path.

Comment: Doh! I just read your question again and realise what you mean. Yes, marker icons can be dynamically swapped with `marker.setIcon(url);`. I have updated the code above and the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acMS8/6/). In the fiddle I've used a couple of hot-linked icons from "http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/ but you will use images from your own server, with relative urls.

Comment: thanks so so much, you have saved me so much time helping with this, very much appreciated :)

Comment: hey, any idea what would cause the infobox text to show up as undefined in ie7 and 8?

Comment: I can only think to try grabbing `.text()` instead of `.html()` (three times) in `composeInfoString()`.

Comment: Hey thanks, sadly no joy, I had html in my last one which worked ok in IE. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Mmmm odd, works in IE9. Try purging the `%` characters from the template and the three `.replace()` expressions. They are not necessary except to ensure the placeholders are unique within the template.