# adding an event listener that operates with Google Maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

For the longest time I have not been able to add event listener in the links in the wineries A-Z section for my website (the green button above the map):

http://www.michiganwinetrail.com/

The problem is that I have previously created a loop that is pretty complicated

```
for (var i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++) {

    locations[i][0] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        title: locations[i][3],
        map: map,
        content: locations[i][4]
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

    google.maps.event.addListener(locations[i][0], 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(this.content);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });

}
```

What do i need to add to this loop that will allow my my infowindows to pop up when I click the links in the wineries A-Z section? I would like to stay away from jquery if at all possible

Comment: You're already loading jQuery twice on your page so I don't think you should be averse to using it. Here's a question that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15192164/jquery-google-maps-open-infowindow-on-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a unique ID for your locations in the locations Array like this:

```
var locations[0] = ['twoLads',44.932317,-85.492437, '2 Lads', twoLads_content];
var locations[1] =  ['belLago',44.8529,-85.7663, 'Bel Lago', belLago_content];
//etc...
```

Now you can add a click listener to each "Map It!" link like this:

```
<tr class="rowClass">
<td>Bel Lago</td>
<td><a href="http://bellago.com/">Visit Website</a></td>
<td class="mapIt"><a onclick="openMarker(1);">Map It!</a></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can define a function to handle the opening of the infoWindow.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= locations.length; i++) {

locations[i][0] = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    title: locations[i][3],
    map: map,
    content: locations[i][4]
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});

google.maps.event.addListener(locations[i][0], 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(this.content);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

}

window.openMarker = function(locationId){
    // Set content according to the locationId
    infowindow.setContent(locations[locationId][4]);
    // Open the infowindow at the location of the appropriate marker which gets stored in array key 0 in your loop above.
    infowindow.open(map, locations[locationId][0]);
}
```

Comment: yeah but where in the loop would this second part go?

Comment: The 2nd part doesn't belong in the loop at all.  It is just declared once.  I will update my answer to reflect complete code.

Comment: ok so my next question is, why do i have to store them like that, isn't locations[0] already the first line of values in the array?

Comment: There is no reason for this to break your map?  Can you produce a JSfiddle.net showing how you implemented it and we can then troubleshoot?

Comment: i broke up the array and arranged it how you showed me, I am at work right now, but I guess i could do it later.